# How to subset a dataframe based on the max of a variable?

Tags: r, max, subset

I have a dataset that looks something like the table below with multiple lines corresponding to each month, the count of how many sightings of a certain bird there are (n), and in what region that sighting occurred.

| MONTH | REGION | n |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | North | 12 |
| 1 | South | 45 |
| 2 | West | 34 |
| 2 | South | 23 |
| 2 | East | 32 |
| 3 | North | 11 and so on. |

What I am looking to do is to create a separate dataset that extracts the region with the most sightings per month, so the goal is something that looks like this:

| MONTH | REGION | n |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | South | 45 |
| 2 | West | 34 |
| 3 | North | 11 |

So far I have tried different combinations of piping such as
`df %>% group_by(MONTH) %>% max(n)`, but none have gave the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You could use :

```
library(dplyr)
# your original data
df <- data.frame(
  MONTH = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3),
  REGION = c("North", "South", "West", "South", "East", "North"),
  n = c(12, 45, 34, 23, 32, 11)
)


# extract the regions with most sightings 
df_max <- df %>%
    group_by(MONTH) %>%
 slice(which.max(n))

#result
df_max
# A tibble: 3 × 3
# Groups:   MONTH [3]
  MONTH REGION     n
  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
1     1 South     45
2     2 West      34
3     3 North     11
```